# Which surface is formed by rotating a hyperbola around its asymptotes?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I don't know even what a type of surface will be.
And what equation will be?
The equation of hyperbola - 
$$
xy = l.
$$
Now, let's

$$
x = x'cos(\varphi ) - y'sin(\varphi ), y = x'sin(\varphi ) + y'cos(\varphi ) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}sin(2 \varphi )x'^{2} - \frac{1}{2}sin(2 \varphi )y'^{2} + x'y'cos(2 \varphi) = l.
$$

So

$$
cos( 2 \varphi ) = 0 \Rightarrow \varphi = \frac{\pi}{4} \Rightarrow \frac{x'^{2}}{2l} - \frac{y'^{2}}{2l} = 1.
$$

Comment: A rotated hyperbola!(?) But, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: It's equation. I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately, some object doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to rotate it around $x$ and find the result, then go back to the original hyperbola and rotate it around $y$ and find the result?  Or rotate it around $x$ and rotate the resulting surface around $y$?  The second result looks like a mess to me, and it will depend upon the order of rotation.

Comment: other hiperbola, sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If you rotate a curve in the $xy$ plane around the $x$ axis, each point $(a,b,0)$ will trace out a circle parallel to the $yz$ plane.  The $x$ position of all points on the circle will be the same as the original point, $a$, all the points on the circle will be the same distance from the axis, $b$.

This is presuming the correct reading of the question is the first in my comment.